# Selecting Rowcount and number of columns with one sql query?

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008

How can i club both the select count and select columns with one statement?

Comment: You need to expand on your question. What do you mean by number of columns? In a normal `SELECT` statement you will provide the columns explicitly anyway...

Comment: @ElRonnoco i edited the question..kindly look at it..

Comment: You'll need to show your query statements. This still isn't clear, at least to me.

Comment: SELECT @TotalResultCount = COUNT(id) FROM <TableName>  (for count) and   SELECT Id, Subject,Status,AssignedToName FROM ActivitySubset. The subset contains sorting these columns ..

Answer (score 2):

If you are just looking to see what "shape" your tables are in, something like this would work. But if you're wanting to know column/row counts for a given query, it may be possible but I don't know how to do it

```
; WITH ROW_COUNTS AS
(
SELECT
    s.[Name] as [SchemaName]
,   t.[name] as [TableName]
,   SUM(p.rows) as [RowCounts]
FROM 
    sys.schemas s
    LEFT JOIN 
        sys.tables t
        ON s.schema_id = t.schema_id
    LEFT JOIN 
        sys.partitions p
        ON t.object_id = p.object_id
    LEFT JOIN  
        sys.allocation_units a
        ON p.partition_id = a.container_id
WHERE 
    p.index_id  in(0,1) -- 0 heap table , 1 table with clustered index
    AND p.rows is not null
    AND a.type = 1  -- row-data only , not LOB
GROUP BY 
    s.[Name]
,   t.[name]
)
, COLUMN_COUNTS AS
(
SELECT
    s.[Name] as [SchemaName]
,   t.[name] as [TableName]
,   COUNT(c.column_id) as [ColumnCounts]
FROM 
    sys.schemas s
    INNER JOIN 
        sys.tables t
        ON s.schema_id = t.schema_id
    INNER JOIN
        sys.columns c
        ON C.object_id = T.object_id
GROUP BY 
    s.[Name]
,   t.[name]
)
SELECT
    CC.SchemaName
,   CC.TableName
,   RC.RowCounts
,   CC.ColumnCounts
FROM
    COLUMN_COUNTS CC
    INNER JOIN
        ROW_COUNTS RC
        ON RC.SchemaName = CC.SchemaName
        AND RC.TableName = CC.TableName
ORDER BY
    1,2
```

Results run against master

```
SchemaName  TableName               RowCounts   ColumnCounts
dbo         Hold_Cluster_Status     0           10
dbo         MSreplication_options   3           6
dbo         spt_fallback_db         0           8
dbo         spt_fallback_dev        0           10
dbo         spt_fallback_usg        0           9
dbo         spt_monitor             1           11
dbo         spt_values              2506        6
```

Answer (score 2):

Using a COUNT() window aggregate you should be able to accomplish what you are looking to do. However, the DISTINCT against a very large table is not likely to be very performant:

```
SELECT DISTINCT a, b, c, COUNT(*) OVER (PARTITION BY 1) FROM <tablename>;
```

Another option would be but you are touching the table twice:

```
SELECT a,b,c, MyCount
FROM <tablename>
CROSS JOIN
    (SELECT COUNT(*) AS MyCount
     FROM <tablename>
    )
```

Comment: BTW: `COUNT(*) OVER ()` has the same effect.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not 100% ure what you want, but here is a possible example...

```
SELECT
  a,
  b,
  c,
  (SELECT COUNT(*) FROM yourTable) as table_count
FROM
  yourTable
```